# Is it possible to setup a KVM switch to support both DVI and VGA video sources?

Tags: keyboard-video-mouse

To control a set of servers from a single console and the machines have mixed VGA and DVI video output, is it still possible to just have one console control everything? That is, get video output from any one of the servers to a single monitor (DVI)? KVMs seem to support only DVI or VGA but not both.

Has anyone come up with a solution to this scenario besides just swapping out any old VGA video cards with DVI (which is not always possible, esp. for legacy machines)? If all machines are DVI then of course one would just use DVI KVM switch.

Is there a way to solve this besides resorting to having two separate monitors and two dedicated KVM switches: one for DVI and for VGA machines. I'm not looking for any product recommendations just how and if this can really be solved.

Comment: You can use two kvms and a single monitor that has both dvi and vga inputs...try to get one where switching inputs takes a single button press.  Not perfect, but at least only requires one monitor.